# How to create a bar graph for 2 different variables in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to plot a bar graph using relevant libraries, `matplotlib` or `seaborn` or `pandas`.
Two bar graphs that show the total number of both, ***American Airline*** & ***American Eagle Airline*** flights, for every year.
But not a stacked bar plot.

My current `df` looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2005-07-01','2005-07-01','2005-07-01','2005-08-01',
                           '2007-08-01', '2007-22-04', '2008-07-06'],
                   'Flight Name':['American Airline','American Airline','American Airline','American Eagle Airline',
                                  'American Eagle Airline','American Airline','American Eagle Airline'],
                   'GEO Summary':['Domestic','Domestic','Domestic','International',
                                  'International','Domestic','International'],
                   'Flight Name Variable':[1,1,1,0,0,1,0]})
```

| Date | Flight Name | GEO Summary | Flight Name Variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-07-01 | American Airline | Domestic | 1 |
| 2005-07-01 | American Airline | Domestic | 1 |
| 2005-07-01 | American Airline | Domestic | 1 |
| 2006-08-01 | American Eagle Airline | International | 0 |
| 2007-08-01 | American Eagle Airline | International | 0 |
| 2007-22-04 | American Airline | Domestic | 1 |
| 2008-07-06 | American Eagle Airline | International | 0 |

What I have tried so far and its not working;

`ax = df['Flight Name Variable'].value_counts().plot.bar(color=["SkyBlue","IndianRed"], rot=0, title="test")`

`plt.tight_layout()`
`plt.show()`

I cant seem to find a solution to get the yearly dates to display on the x-axis. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? It is using matplotlib.pyplot and seaborn and shows the total count of those flights on that date:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2005-07-01','2005-07-01','2005-07-01','2005-08-01','2005-07-01', '2005-08-01', '2005-08-01'],
                   'Flight Name':['American Airline','American Airline','American Airline','American Eagle Airline','American Eagle Airline','American Airline','American Eagle Airline'],
                   'GEO Summary':['Domestic','Domestic','Domestic','International','International','Domestic','International'],
                   'Flight Name Variable':[1,1,1,0,0,1,0]})
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.date # Convert the string dates to actual datetime values
grouped = df.groupby(by=["Flight Name", "Date"], as_index=False).count()
sns.barplot(data=grouped, x="Date", y="Flight Name Variable", hue="Flight Name")
plt.title("Flights")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Or with more grouping/variables for the hue setting:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2005-07-01','2005-07-01','2005-07-01','2005-08-01','2005-07-01', '2005-08-01', '2005-08-01'],
                   'Flight Name':['American Airline','American Airline','American Airline','American Eagle Airline','American Eagle Airline','American Airline','American Eagle Airline'],
                   'GEO Summary':['International','Domestic','Domestic','International','International','Domestic','International'],
                   'Flight Name Variable':[1,1,1,0,0,1,0]})
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.date # Convert the string dates to actual datetime values
grouped = df.groupby(by=["Flight Name", "Date", "GEO Summary"], as_index=False).count()

# Define your Hue to be both the Flight Name and the GEO Summary and place them in a nice looking format with lambda
hue = grouped[['Flight Name', 'GEO Summary']].apply(lambda row: f"{row['Flight Name']}, {row['GEO Summary']}", axis=1)
sns.barplot(data=grouped, x="Date", y="Flight Name Variable", hue=hue)
plt.title("Flights")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

Output[image]

Comment: @Qas Great! I also added an option to increase the variables/groups for the hue (to include if they were domestic or international). I don't think your data had American Airline as ever being International, but I wanted to show you how you could incorporate that if necessary

Comment: thank you for your input. Ive been on this for 2 days now.

Comment: Im having issues with the 'Date' column. Originally they are in datetime64 format. Im getting an error, 'Could not interpret input 'Date''. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Sure thing. My dates were just strings that I put together and I assumed yours would be loaded in as dates. You can do `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)` to put it in the format with the date and time or you can do `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.date` to make it just display the date (and not have the 0:00:00 time at the end) ... I updated the answer with this conversion